# How to partition a table into many files to a s3 storage by using nos_write in tera data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, teradata

I have  a  sql like below， it can write data to a S3  Storage ，

but only write one file， and file name can't be controlled by myself.

see   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL3PV.jpg

How to partition table to many files by using the nos_write command (modify sql command like below )?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT82W.jpg  (this upload by myself)

How to  control the file name? (default like this : object_33_1_1.parquet )

```
SELECT  ObjectSize, RecordCount
FROM WRITE_NOS_FM (
 ON  ( SELECT * FROM RiverFlowPerm_csv )
 USING
  LOCATION('/s3/bigXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/RiverFlowPerm/')
  STOREDAS('PARQUET')
  COMPRESSION('GZIP')
) AS d ;
```

**above question is OK**

---

**2021/5/21**

---

How to make it  partition  into  **more than one level directory**.

example:   /RiverFlowPerm/1/SiteNo/FLOW
How to do it?
this sql below show me  an error message :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb4xX.jpg

```
SELECT ObjectSize, RecordCount 
FROM WRITE_NOS_FM ( 
ON ( SELECT * FROM RiverFlowPerm_csv ) 
PARTITION BY SiteNo,FLOW ORDER BY SiteNo,FLOW 
USING LOCATION('/s3/biXXXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/RiverFlowPerm/1/') 
STOREDAS('PARQUET')
NAMING('DISCRETE') 
INCLUDE_ORDERING('TRUE') 
MAXOBJECTSIZE('4MB') 
COMPRESSION('GZIP') ) AS d ORDER BY AmpId;
```

I don't know how to fix it according to the error message.

Schema is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbfM6.jpg

Comment: Files are named based on ORDER BY and the NAMING option.

Comment: I tried as  you said.  It works  :    https://imgur.com/a/JcgbwX3                             https://imgur.com/a/5lVVKsa

Comment: append  a new question  above

Comment: You can't ORDER BY a FLOAT, must be a column with discrete values, e.g. INT, VARCHAR, DATE

Comment: The  value  to be partition can not be  null  (has  null value) , am I right ?